TKinter crashing because of a while loop
I wrote this code for my program and it started crashing when i added a while loop:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pyautogui
import time
#3 We define the spam command
spamming=False
**def spam():
    global clickidy
    clickidy=f"{tipidytype.get()}"
    global spamming
    spamming= not(spamming)
    while spamming==True:
            pyautogui.press("a")
            time.sleep(1)**
#1 Lets set up our window
root=Tk()
root["bg"]="#fafafa"
root.title("Sigma clicker")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
frame=Frame()
frame.place(relx=0,rely=0,relheight=1,relwidth=1)
#2 Now we can add interface
title = Label(frame, text="Enter the button for spamming here")
title.place(x=15, y=15)
tipidytype=Entry(frame,bg="white")
tipidytype.place(x=15, y=45)
**button = Button(frame,text="      Press/F7     ", bg="gray", command=spam)**
button.place(x=15,y=75)
root.mainloop()

It worked when i changed while loop for an "if" statement but i need an infinite loop. I have a suspicion that the main tkinter window loop cant co-exist with a while loop. Because my window stops responding but the typing works

yes, you cannot have commands that do infinite loops, because the app needs to execute other tasks like drawing the window, you can just have another thread do it, something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71226899/15649230

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131486/tkinter-root-mainloop-with-while-true-loop

When you run endless loop directly from the function tkinter tends to crack. Instead import threading module and run thru another function. For ensuring 'a' is pressed, I changed the line pyautogui.press("a") to print('a') so that I can view the output in the terminal. Please note that clickidy is declared but not used anywhere in your code. So if you want clickid to be the output change print('a') to print(clickidy).
The following code gives output 'a' for every second once you press the button. If you press the same button again, it will stop.
from tkinter import *
import time
import threading
#3 We define the spam command
spamming = False

def spam():
    global spamming
    global clickidy
    spamming = not(spamming)
    clickidy=f"{tipidytype.get()}"
    
    # Make the condition based on the button's text
    if button.cget('text') == 'Start spamming':
        button.config(text = 'Stop spamming')
        
        # run thru another function using threading module
        threading.Thread(target = endless_print).start()
    else: button.config(text = 'Start spamming')        
                    
def endless_print():
    global spamming
    global clickidy
    while spamming:
        print('a')
        time.sleep(1)
        
#1 Lets set up our window
root=Tk()
root["bg"]="#fafafa"
root.title("Sigma clicker")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
frame=Frame()
frame.place(relx=0,rely=0,relheight=1,relwidth=1)
#2 Now we can add interface
title = Label(frame, text="Enter the button for spamming here")
title.place(x=15, y=15)
tipidytype=Entry(frame,bg="white")
tipidytype.place(x=15, y=45)
button = Button(frame,text="Start spamming", bg="gray", command=spam)
button.place(x=15,y=75)
root.mainloop()


Threading module doesnt work for me (idk why) but i found a way around it by just adding root.update() in the while loop so when the loop is active it update by the update command and when the loop is not active window updates by the mainloop

@Carnypex, I posted the answer only after ensuring that it's working.
